# NullPointerException while implementing Queue using Linked List

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, queue

I am following Coursera Algorithm 1 course, and right now implementing Queues using linked list, but getting a `NullPointerException`. Please help me out.

```
package algo_packages;

public class QueueLinkedList {
    private Node first, last;
    public class Node{
        String item;
        Node next;
    }

    public QueueLinkedList(){
        first = null;
        last = null;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return first == last;
    }
    public void enqueue(String item){
        Node oldLast = last;
        last = new Node();
        last.item = item;
        last.next = null;
        if(isEmpty()){
            first = last;
        }
        else {
            oldLast.next = last;
        }
    }
    public String dequeue(){
        String item = first.item;
        first = first.next;
        if (isEmpty()) last = null;
        return item;
    }
}
```

I am getting the exception at:

```
oldLast.next = last;
```

`oldLast.next` caused the `NullPointerException` when I tried to debug the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you check isEmpty() it always returns false for enqueue because you are setting last to a new Node() which will never equal first.  You don't need to check if list isEmpty() because if list is empty then first == last so you don't need to assign first = last because they are already equal.  Try this:

```
public void enqueue(String item){
    Node oldLast = last;
    last = new Node();
    last.item = item;
    last.next = null;
    if(oldLast != null)
    {
        oldLast.next = last;
    }
    else
    {
        first = last;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first time you enqueue an item `isEmpty()` returns false, since it checks if `first==last`, but `first` is still null and `last` is no longer null (since you already assigned the new `Node` to it). This brings you to access `oldLast.next` when `oldLast` is null, hence the `NullPointerException`.

A possible fix :

```
public void enqueue(String item)
{
    Node oldLast = last;
    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.item = item;
    newNode.next = null;
    if(isEmpty()) { // last is not assigned yet, so isEmpty returns correct result
        last = newNode;
        first = last;
    } else {
        last = newNode;
        oldLast.next = last;
    }
}
```